# VMware Workstation has terrible performance on local hard disk

Tags: windows-xp, performance, vmware-workstation, virtual-drive

I'm working on vmware image files. My computer always load hard disk and vmware works very slow at the same time.

Guest OS: Windows XP SP2
Host  OS: Windows XP SP2

Is there any way can improve the performance?

Comment: Do you have enough system resources allocated to your VMs?

Does your CPU have support for Virtual Machines (and is that support enabled in bios?)

Comment: How much memory does your guest operating system have? As a percentage of your total memory.

Comment: ... and how much memory does the HOST OS (XP) have?

Answer (score 1):

From your question it sounds like the guest OS hard drive is an image file on the host OS.  VmWare has the ability to write directly to a partition instead of an image file.  That should speed up the hard drive access for the Guest OS.

Also as other comments suggested, increase the RAM on your computer, getting a faster hard drive (higher RPMs) should also help out.